# Gas water pipe corrosion.... Can It be fixed?

Tags: water, gas, heater, copper

My gas water heater pipes have corrosion at the copper to galvanized metal connection. Can it be fixed, and if so with what and how?

[image: Corrosion on gas pipe]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. First thing: **get your gas turned off!** That section of pipe could fail at any moment, which would likely destroy your house and/or kill people. Then, come back and we may have a good answer for you.

Comment: Is that a water pipe that's corroded or a gas pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that’s galvanized? Everything else (I know it dirty and hard to see) looks like black pipe. Which makes sense. But galvanized and gas is a huge no no. If it’s a water pipe, then turn off water heater and everything else and unthread that piece of pipe and get a new piece from a home improvement store.

Answer (score 0):

Water is apparently leaking from the bottom fitting of the galvanized union and causing corrosion of the galvanized steel pipe. Remove the union, clean the threads , apply pipe dope ( I prefer teflon tape) and reassemble tightly to prevent future leaks. The rusted pipe could be wire brushed clean and will not rust if kept dry.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a water connection and if it is a water connection I'd suggest upgrading the pipes to either copper or PEX.

Iron (Galvanized or not) will always deteriorate with water and in a few/couple years you will have another leak.